# URL rewrite http to https but not on standard 443 port

Tags: url-rewrite-module, iis-8.5

I want to use URL rewrite module in IIS 8.5 to redirect any non-https traffic from http://something.com:112 to https://something.com:444 (notice these are not standard http and https port numbers).

I tried using this rewrite rule but it doesn't work:

```
<rewrite>
<rules>
    <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
        <add input="{SERVER_PORT}" pattern="^444$" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}:444/{R:1}" redirectType="Found" />
    </rule>
</rules>
</rewrite>
```

The error I get in the Failed Requests Logs is:

ModuleName IIS Web Core 
Notification MAP_REQUEST_HANDLER 
HttpStatus 404 
HttpReason Not Found 
HttpSubStatus 0 
ErrorCode The system cannot find the file specified. (0x80070002)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Small update, in Safari browser I was able to finally figure out that the URL is being changed to https://something.com:112:444/. How to take out the ":112" from the final URL?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, I was incorrectly using HTTP_POST, this contains both SERVER_NAME and HTTP_PORT. Instead, I used this action and it seems to work just fine:

I also noticed I didn't need to check for both conditions. This one actually does what I need since we have some websites running on other https ports:

```
<rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS on port 444" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://{SERVER_NAME}:444/{R:1}" redirectType="Found" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
</rewrite>
```